# Create layout for multiple devices

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

everyone. I want to create a layout for multiple devices. To do this, I select my original layout in Android Studio and thought I could do this using the "Orientation for Preview" icon. Unfortunately I can't find the entry "create other" there. Where can I now create my layout for other devices?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the device dropdown just on the right ("`Pixel`"):

[image]

Then you can choose an pre-defined device/resolution, or you can create your own device/resolution.

[image]